# RESTful Routes help in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using Rails 3, Devise and Mongoid.

I believe I can accomplish what I need using RESTful Routes but I am not sure how to do it. Let me explain what I have and what I am trying to do.

Let's say I have two controllers - User and Simpleform.

The Simpleform is a public facing form (no authentication required) that when submitted shows up in a user's account (when they login).

I have multipul users on the system and each one will see the form submissions that's specific to them.

So the question is, how do I get the public facing form to submit to a specific user's account?

As of now the route to fill out a new form looks like this "site.com/simpleform/new". I think I can use routes to make it look like this "site.com/simpleform/user_id/new" or "site.com/user_id/simpleform/new". Either variation would work I think. Now when the form is submitted from someone in the public the application knows what user to associate it too because of the user_id in the url.

I think that logic works and RESTful Routes can make it happen, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: can you clarify, please. You say no authentication will be required to submit a Simpleform but you want it to be associated with a User? Somehow you have to provide a user ID to associate the Simpleform with the user. Either the user has to be logged in when s/he submits the form (a simple nested resource). Or the form has to include a field for the user ID (allowing anyone to associate the simpleform with any user). Do you wish to require a user to be logged in before they access and submit the SimpleForm?

Comment: Or do you want anyone to see the SimpleForm and then be forced to log in when they try to submit the form?

Comment: Neither. Let's say you have Company A and "the public (many people)". Company A has an account with my app and has a form they want to put on their site. Anyone can fill out the form on Company A's site and submit it (no authentication required). However, Company A needs to login to the system in order to see the submitted form. Several companies have accounts with my app, so I need a way to know when a public facing form is submitted which company it belongs to. Thus the solution of having the company ID in the form's url. Does that make a little more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each User resource has one associated SimpleForm resource.

So I would think your route would be like:

```
  resources :users do
    resource :simpleform
  end
```

And routes would look like:

```
     user_simpleform POST   /users/:user_id/simpleform(.:format)                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
 new_user_simpleform GET    /users/:user_id/simpleform/new(.:format)              {:action=>"new", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
edit_user_simpleform GET    /users/:user_id/simpleform/edit(.:format)             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
                     GET    /users/:user_id/simpleform(.:format)                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/simpleform(.:format)                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/simpleform(.:format)                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"simpleforms"}
               users GET    /users(.:format)                                      {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
                     POST   /users(.:format)                                      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
```

Comment: This worked. I have to figure out some of the authentication permissions with different aspects of the form (edit vs new vs show etc) - but that isn't part of this question. Thanks for the help.